# Auto position tooltip when exceed on browser's width

Tags: jquery, css

What I want to happen is when the tooltip width exceeds to browser's viewable area, it will automatically re-position itself, so the content can be viewed fully. The tooltip should not overlap on referenced div. The tooltip should not resize width or height when re-positioning itself. Please help.

Here is my sample [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/epJjN/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

**See Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/mpDXY/

**Reference Website:** http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/htmltooltip.shtml

Comment: You may see the js file `htmltooltip.js` having function `positiontip:function($, tipindex, e)` Path for the JS file: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/htmltooltip.js

Comment: Yup, I just saw it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Now I have made my own plugin to autoposition an object:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.autoposition = function(ref, opt){     
            var _this = $(this);
            var position = function(_tip, _ref, opt){
            var o = $.extend({
                "topallowance":0,
                "leftallowance":0
            }, o || opt);

            var _window = $(window);
            var _widthOfWindow = _window.width();
            var _widthDifferenceFromXaxisOfRef = _widthOfWindow - _ref.offset().left;
            var _xAdjustmentOftipWhenExceedAtLeftSide = ((_tip.outerWidth() > _widthDifferenceFromXaxisOfRef) ? (_tip.outerWidth() - _widthDifferenceFromXaxisOfRef) + o.leftallowance : 0);
            var _leftOfTheTip = _ref.offset().left - _xAdjustmentOftipWhenExceedAtLeftSide;

            var _heightOfWindow = _window.outerHeight();
            var _heightDifferenceFromYaxisOfRef = _heightOfWindow - (_ref.offset().top + _ref.outerHeight());
            var _topOfTheTip = (_tip.outerHeight() > _heightDifferenceFromYaxisOfRef) ? (_ref.offset().top - _tip.outerHeight()) - o.topallowance : (_heightOfWindow - _heightDifferenceFromYaxisOfRef) + o.topallowance;



            _tip
                .css('position', 'absolute')
                .css('top', _topOfTheTip)
                .css('left', _leftOfTheTip)
            ;
        };

        position(_this, ref, opt);
        $(window).bind('resize', function(){
            position(_this, ref, opt);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

To use it:

```
$(".TooltipSample").autoposition($(".theObjectWhereTheTooltipWillShow"));
```

Hope it could help to others.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution and done on codebins as follows:

1) Include jquery-1.2.2.pack.js and htmltooltip.js javascript files on header.

2) write HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    A
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    B
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    C
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    D
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    E
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    F
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    G
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    H
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    I
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    J
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    K
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    L
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    M
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    N
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    O
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    P
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    Q
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    R
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    S
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    T
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    U
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    V
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    W
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    X
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    Y
  </div>
  <div rel="htmltooltip">
    Z
  </div>
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div A
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div B
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div C
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div D
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div E
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div F
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div G
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div H
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div I
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div J
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div K
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div L
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div M
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div N
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div O
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div P
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div Q
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div R
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div S
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div T
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div U
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div V
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div W
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div X
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div Y
</div>
<div class="htmltooltip">
  Showing Tooltip for Div Z
</div>
```

Write CSS:

```
#container div{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:80px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #5544d6;
  background-color:#441591;
  color:#cda923;
}
div.htmltooltip{
  position: absolute;
  /*leave this and next 3 values alone*/
  z-index: 1000;
  left: -1000px;
  top: -1000px;
  background: #2255a9;
  border: 7px solid #4488a9;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 3px #446689;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align:center;

  width: 250px;
  /*width of tooltip*/
}
```

On Above Html, we have set rel attribute with "htmltooltip" on each tag and according to its order we have set related tooltip with class "htmltooltip". now it shows order wise realted tooltip on mouse over of each tag.

It also check auto position of tooltip div and if exceeds then browser width then it shows tooltip inside browser area.

Try Demo here : http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbl